# Filter Air coming through window

Tags: windows, air-quality

There is a window in my back side of the house. i wanted to keep open the window of the backside just to keep the house warm. but there is a public bathroom in the backside and i feel very bad smell most of the time.

Is there anyway that i can prevent bad smell coming into my house. wil it be working if i cover the window with a cloth which we used to make Face masking ?

or else is there any other way ?

Answer (score 3):

You could Have an HVAC company install an electronic air cleaner with a charcoal pre or post filter in that window. This would remove most if not all of the smell, but would cost a significant amount. You could also install an exhaust fan in that window if there is another window you could open to allow air in for the required ventilation, say from the front or side of the house. Blowing air out would not allow the smell in. Regular cloth coverings or filters in a window will not take out the smells.

Comment: There is one more item that I forgot to mention. There is a cut-to size filter that comes in 20"x24" that has a plastic framing, a green filter and a charcoal filter. You can use it full size or any size you prefer. I buy them in Home Depot or Lowes for about $10.00. I use them in my furnace to eliminate smells in my house. My wife hates certain smells and this filter eliminates those smells. If it works for you it would be a cheap fix. by the way it is called "the web absorber"